# Clearos - how to fix package dependency error

Tags: yum, clearos

I have been running ClearOs Community Edition 7 for ages. At some time in the past, I installed mono (which I have since removed).
I just noticed the system has not been updating - when I do yum update, I get this error:

```
Error: Package: glibc-2.17-317.el7.i686 (clearos-centos)
           Requires: glibc-common = 2.17-317.el7
           Removing: glibc-common-2.17-260.el7_6.6.x86_64 (@centos-updates-unverified)
               glibc-common = 2.17-260.el7_6.6
           Updated By: glibc-common-2.17-326.el7_9.x86_64 (clearos-centos-updates)
               glibc-common = 2.17-326.el7_9
           Available: glibc-common-2.17-317.el7.x86_64 (clearos-centos)
               glibc-common = 2.17-317.el7
           Available: glibc-common-2.17-322.el7_9.x86_64 (clearos-centos-updates)
               glibc-common = 2.17-322.el7_9
           Available: glibc-common-2.17-323.el7_9.x86_64 (clearos-centos-updates)
               glibc-common = 2.17-323.el7_9
           Available: glibc-common-2.17-324.el7_9.x86_64 (clearos)
               glibc-common = 2.17-324.el7_9
           Available: glibc-common-2.17-325.el7_9.x86_64 (clearos-centos-updates)
               glibc-common = 2.17-325.el7_9
```

But I am at a total loss to understand the error, or to fix it.

Is the cause because, to install mono I had to add additional repos, and they have now screwed things up?

Is there any way out of this, without reinstalling ClearOs from scratch?

Further info:

```
# yum update glibc --disablerepo=* --enablerepo=clearos
Loaded plugins: clearcenter-marketplace, fastestmirror
ClearCenter Marketplace: fetching repositories...
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * clearos: mirror1-amsterdam.clearos.com
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package glibc.x86_64 0:2.17-260.el7_6.6 will be updated
---> Package glibc.x86_64 0:2.17-324.el7_9 will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: glibc-common = 2.17-324.el7_9 for package: glibc-2.17-324.el7_9.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package glibc-common.x86_64 0:2.17-260.el7_6.6 will be updated
--> Processing Dependency: glibc-common = 2.17-260.el7_6.6 for package: glibc-2.17-260.el7_6.6.i686
---> Package glibc-common.x86_64 0:2.17-324.el7_9 will be an update
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: glibc-2.17-260.el7_6.6.i686 (@centos-updates-unverified)
           Requires: glibc-common = 2.17-260.el7_6.6
           Removing: glibc-common-2.17-260.el7_6.6.x86_64 (@centos-updates-unverified)
               glibc-common = 2.17-260.el7_6.6
           Updated By: glibc-common-2.17-324.el7_9.x86_64 (clearos)
               glibc-common = 2.17-324.el7_9
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```